# a group is not the union of two proper subgroups - how to internalize this into other categories?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

A well-known fact from group theory is that a group cannot be the union of two proper subgroups. I wonder, does this statement [internalize](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internalization) into other categories than the category of sets? That is, is there some corresponding statement for [group object](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group+object)s in, say, [cartesian categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+monoidal+category)? It is certainly true for topoi, interpreted in a suitable way, since the usual proof is intuistic (however, note that $G=G_1 \cup G_2 \Rightarrow G=G_1 \vee G=G_2$ fails for disconnected topoi).

What about the following: Let $G:=(|G|,m,i,e)$ be a group object in the cartesian category $\mathcal{C}$. Let $G_1 \to G$ and $G_2 \to G$ be homomorphisms of group objects, which are no isomorphisms. Assume that $|G_1| \to |G|$ and $|G_2| \to |G|$ are monomorphisms. Is it not possible that $|G| \to |G|$ is their union, i.e. their sup in the preorder of subobjects of $|G|$?

Well as I've said, it fails for disconnected topoi. What do we have to assume on $\mathcal{C}$ so that it becomes true?

Comment: Actually, there's an easy counterexample in $\mathbf{Grp}$ as well, since internal groups there are just abelian groups.

Comment: You are right. Please undelete your answer :). Although I've asked for general assumptions, examples are also welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, another easy counterexample. Recall that an internal group in $\mathbf{Grp}$ is just an abelian group. So consider $G = \mathbb{Z} / 6 \mathbb{Z}$, let $G_1$ be the unique subgroup of order 2, and let $G_2$ be the unique subgroup of order 3. Then the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $G_1$ and $G_2$ is $G$ itself, so the claim fails in $\mathbf{Grp}$ as well.

---

Now, for some slightly more positive results. Let's recall the standard proof. Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be subgroups of $G$. Suppose $G = G_1 \cup G_2$, $g_1 \notin G_2$, $g_2 \notin G_1$. Consider $g_1 g_2$. If $g_1 g_2 \in G_1$, then $g_2 \in G_1$, a contradiction; and if $g_1 g_2 \in G_2$, then $g_1 \in G_2$ , also a contradiction. Thus, $g_1 g_2 \notin G_1 \cup G_2$, so $G \ne G_1 \cup G_2$.

As you say, this is intuitionistically valid. In fact it can even be interpreted in any [coherent category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coherent+category). The only problem is that it does not mean what you think it means! The right formulation is the following:

> If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are subgroups of $G$ and we (simultaneously) have (generalised) elements of $G \setminus G_1$ and $G \setminus G_2$, then $G \ne G_1 \cup G_2$.

More formally,
$$g_1 \notin G_2, g_2 \notin G_1 \vdash_{g_1 : G, g_2 : G} \lnot (\forall g : G . g \in G_1 \lor g \in G_2)$$
but having $g_2 \notin G_1$ is generally a stronger condition than $G_1 \hookrightarrow G$ not being an isomorphism. In general, $G_1 \hookrightarrow G$ in an isomorphism (in a topos) if and only if the following formula holds in the internal logic:
$$\forall g : G . g \in G_1$$
Unfortunately, it is not possible to express internally that a formula does *not* hold! Although we may write
$$\lnot (\forall g : G . g \in G_1)$$
the above formula asserts that $G_1 \hookrightarrow G$ is not even an isomorphism *locally*: in a topos, the above formula is valid if and only if, for every $U$, the induced map $\mathrm{Hom}(U, G_1) \to \mathrm{Hom}(U, G)$ is not a surjection. Clearly, this is a stronger condition than $G_1 \hookrightarrow G$ not being an isomorphism.

Nonetheless, we may deduce that the claim is true for *complemented* proper subgroups $G_1$, $G_2$ in a topos in which the subobjects of $1$ form an irreducible locale: because under these hypotheses, the locus $U$ over which *both* $G \setminus G_1$ and $G \setminus G_2$ is inhabited is non-empty, so $G \ne G_1 \cup G_2$ in the topos over $U$. But this is enough to prove $G \ne G_1 \cup G_2$ globally as well – because passing to the topos over $U$ is a logical functor.

---

**Postscript.** A more sophisticated approach allows us to deduce another version of the claim. Suppose we have subgroups $G_1$ and $G_2$ of an internal group $G$ in a topos such that $G_1 \times G \cup G \times G_2$ is a proper subobject of $G \times G$. Noting that $G = G_1 \cup G_2$ if and only if this is true in all covers of the topos, by passing to a boolean cover if necessary, we may assume the law of excluded middle. But then in that case it is clear that 
$$(G \setminus G_1) \times (G \setminus G_2) = (G \times G) \setminus (G_1 \times G \cup G \times G_2)$$
so the LHS is non-empty. Thus we have reduced the question to the well-known case.

Comment: My previous comments about toposes with enough points were incorrect; please disregard.